# Wireless firmware on late 2011 macbook pro. Can't connect to wireless

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless, firmware, macbook-pro

I dual booted ubuntu with my macbookpro. When I installed the os it worked fine and the only problem is that i can't connect to wireless. It works fine if i hard wire it but i can't get the right firmware for it. I tired going to system settings and then hardware drivers but it doesn't show up. I have been trying to look around for answers but can't see to get anything to work. Please help me out with solutions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try packages listed here: http://philatwarrimoo.blogspot.com.au/2012/09/ubuntu-1210-quantal-on-macbook-pro-81.html

ie.

b43-fwcutter
linux-firmware (probably already installed)
linux-firmware-nonfree
firmware-b43-lpphy-installer

You may not need last one, then reboot.